# Asterisk Func_odbc select multiple values and fetch it in extensions.conf

Tags: sql, unix, odbc, asterisk

I am using `func_odbc` to manipulate dialplan in `extensions.conf
I have 1 select

```
[TEST]
dsn=MSSQL

readsql=select rout,server from Dial_Plan where @bnumb = '${SQL_ESC(${ARG1})}'
```

and I want to fetch it in `extensions.conf` dialplan like this

```
exten => _X.,1,Set(GLOBAL(NUMB2)=Val1)
same => n,Set(GLOBAL(NUMB)=Val2)
```

Comment: Sorry? What is Val2? How it related to your sql?

Answer (score 2):

When calling your ODBC function in dialplan, you can use the array function to set the two

```
exten => _X.,1,Set(ARRAY(GLOBAL(NUMB2),GLOBAL(NUMB))=${ODBC_TEST(${ARG1})})
```

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Function_ARRAY